# Can I use Dataflow for Python SDK from a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to play with [Dataflow for Python SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK) from a Jupyter notebook. I am not sure what are the dependencies needed and if I can spread the code over multiple notebook cells or not. What are the steps involved?

Answer (score 5):

Yes! There are no special steps involved. For example, using a Conda environment (recommended for using IPython/Jupyter notebooks) the commands to start a Jupyter notebook are:

1. conda create -n TESTENV jupyter
2. source activate TESTENV
3. pip install https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK/archive/v0.2.3.tar.gz
4. jupyter notebook

The commands above install version v0.2.3 of Python Dataflow. Please change it to the version desired. In the first notebook cell execute the following import statement:

import google.cloud.dataflow as df

Now you are all set. You can spread the workflow code over multiple cells. Check out the following notebook describing a very simple workflow: https://github.com/silviulica/WorkflowExamples/blob/master/notebooks/HelloWorld.ipynb

Comment: Note, however, that p.run() evaluates all operations added to a pipeline since its creation. In particular, reevaluating a cell multiple times without recreating the pipeline object causes operations to get *added* to the current pipeline--it does not replace the operations added with the previous evaluation of that cell. For this reason it's sometimes simpler to let p.run() be in the same cell as pipeline creation, even if your pipeline construction is spread across several functions and PTransforms defined in other cells.