# no module named facebook in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

EDIT: I think this [Can I use Dataflow for Python SDK from a Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078046/can-i-use-dataflow-for-python-sdk-from-a-jupyter-notebook) answers it. Standby.

I'm a little bored over the holidays and working through Mining the Social Web (from o'reilly media). This is all done in Python, and while i've used python to some extent, I still consider myself a newb.

So, I'm working through an example that requires facebook-sdk. Just for the heck of it, I tried to execute this:

```
virtualenv facebookenv
source facebookenv/bin/activate
pip install facebook-sdk
```

Of course, that gave me the

```
ERROR the executable is not functioning // blah blah
```

I found my way around that with a little bit of searching. Now, obviously just bc I installed facebook-sdk in a virtualenv doesn't mean my instance of Jupyter will automatically find it. Here is the problem: I don't really know where to install said package in order to accomplish this. I'm fairly confident I could achieve this by *not* using a virtualenv, but then that sort of defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

The final problem is, I don't really know what questions to be asking here to get this done.

Please help! (no this is not homework).

Comment: Success! the link above solves this question.

Answer (score -2):

I have this working. The only difference is that I:

1. created the virtual-environment, say jupyterfb, then `cd jupyterfb`
2. activated the environment by using the command `source activate` while in "jupyterfb"
3. installed facebook-sdk and started jupyter `jupyter notebook`